# remove content from start to html tag stored in a variable

Tags: javascript

I am having a html content in a variable like `var content = "<li><div>list 1</div>
<ol><li><div>list nested list 1</div></li></ol></li>";`

I want to remove content till first `</div>` and store removed content in one variable and keep rest in same variable. as below:

```
content = '<ol><li><div>list nested list 1</div></li></ol></li>'
```

and `removed_content= <li><div>list 1</div>`

I tried to use `removed_content =content.replace(/</div>.*/, '');` but its not accepting HTML tag in it.

Comment: Why don't you parse the HTML or insert it into a temporary element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var index = content.indexOf("</div>") + 6; //always gives you the end of first </div> tag
var removed-content = content.substr(0, index);
content = content.substr(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = "<li><div>list 1</div><ol><li><div>list nested list 1</div></li></ol></li>";
var removed_content = "";
var reg = /^(.*?<\/div>)/;
content = content.replace(reg, function(all, $1){
    removed_content = $1;
    return "";
})
```

Comment: Couldn't get this - it's the `.*?` that threw me :)